# Set filename in Base64FileField in django rest framework extra fields

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a Rest API with Django Rest Framework, and in some call, I need upload one of different file types.

For do this, I am using [drf-extra-fields](https://github.com/Hipo/drf-extra-fields) and I have this problem:

When the client convert file to Base64, the filename change and lose the file extension, for suply this, I created in serializer, new CharField called "file_extension":

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Some other fields...
    file = FileField(required=False)
    file_extension = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        # model and fields...
```

I created my custom Base64FileField, and set some allowed types and my method for get file extension:

```
class FileField(Base64FileField):
    ALLOWED_TYPES = ['pdf', 'txt', 'xml']

    def get_file_extension(self, filename, decoded_file):
        # Not working because the filename not include extension.
        return filename.split('.')[-1]
```

For solve this, I thinked set filename in serializer with file extension (taked for the other field) before get_file_extension is called.

Thanks you!

Comment: My question is: How can I set filename in Base64FileField?

Comment: Have you considered using `python-magic`?

See https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic

Comment: Have you seen [DRF base64](https://bitbucket.org/levit_scs/drf_base64/overview)?

Answer (score 1):

Use **filetype** to identify the type of the decoded_file

[filetype - PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/filetype/)

```
import filetype

class FileField(Base64FileField):
    ALLOWED_TYPES = ['pdf', 'txt', 'xml']

    def get_file_extension(self, filename, decoded_file):
        kind = filetype.guess(decoded_file)
        return kind.extension
```